# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError when tried to add new comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have following code in app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    book = Book.find params[:book_id]
    comment = book.comments.new params[:comment]
    comment.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Comment saved'
    redirect_to book_path(book)     
  end
end
```

I am not sure why i am getting error at line         `comment = book.comments.new params[:comment]`

I tried changing `comment = book.comments.new params[:comment]` to `comment = book.comments.new(comment)` but then it didnt show the comment on application when i click save

Also tried doing something like this below

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    book = Book.find params[:book_id]
#    comment = book.comments.new params[:comment]
     comment =  book.comments.new(comment_params)     
    comment.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Comment saved'
    redirect_to book_path(book)     
  end

 def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit()
 end

 end
```

Comment: Can you please look into your server logs (`log/development.log`) and/or the console window, and show us the *full* error message - not just what you have copied as the title, but also a few lines on either side of that. Usually in the server logs you'll get an example of the actual params that were passed, and sometimes it will even tell you *which* attributes were forbidden. Edit your question and add the info there (rather than replying in comments) because code-formatting in comments is unreadable :P

Comment: Also `params.require(:comment).permit()` this is literally telling rails that you permit there to be a `params[:comment]` but that you do not permit any parameters to be within that `params[:comment]` - so if you actually pass something (eg `{ :content => "this is a comment", :author_id => 1234}`) then you will get exactly the error you see. But looking at the logs I've asked for will confirm this(and what you need to do to fix it).

Comment: Thanks I changed it to  @comment = book.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit!)  but it shows comment after i refresh page. I believe it should show it when i hit save

Answer (score 1):

This line (btw `()` are optional)

```
params.require(:comment).permit()
```

simply means you permitted NO attributes to be assigned, thus error.

Add the list of attributes (whitelist them) to be able to assign them:

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :title, :other_attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    book = Book.find params[:book_id]
     #comment = book.comments.new params[:comment]
 @comment = book.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit!)    
     #comment =  book.comments.new(comment_params)     
    #comment.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Comment saved'
    redirect_to book_path(book)     

end
 end
```

Comment: I recommend against `params.require(:comment).permit!` for two reasons. One - traditionally you put this in a separate method, so that it can be reused by the edit/update action as well. Two - this literally permits everything... including permitting the user to use their console to add a `user_id` field and thus create a comment belonging to another user. You really don't want that. You should always white-list the attributes that the user is allowed to change. that's the purpose of having this require/permit line in the first place. :)